# Heroku dataclip variable substitution in query

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I want to set some parameters/variables at the top of the query and use them in several places in a complex query on Heroku Dataclips.
Here is a simple example:

```
WITH vars AS ( SELECT 
  '2018-01-07' AS calcdate,
  12345 AS salary
)
select * 
from taxes
where country_alpha3='USA' and year='2018' and active=true 
and subdivision_code='US-MEDI' 
and local_code is null
and start_date <= DATE(vars.calcdate) and end_date >= DATE(vars.calcdate) 
and lower_amount_cents <= vars.salary and upper_amount_cents >= vars.salary;
```

I saw this style of code in another answer (from 2013) and it is not working in the actual dataclip as of today.

```
Error: Your query couldn't be updated.

ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "vars" 
LINE 12: and start_date <=  DATE(vars.calcdate) and end_date >= DATE(v...
                                 ^
```

If the `vars.calcdate` and `vars.salary`are changed to the constants, then the SQL works fine. It is something to do with the `vars.` syntax or usage, I think.

Comment: why not? witch error? this is standar sql with cte allowed by posgres.

Comment: Edited with error message and exact SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. It was syntax as I supposed. The format of vars.name is not allowed (not certain where I saw that).

```
WITH vars AS ( SELECT
  DATE('2018-01-07') AS calcdate,
  12345 AS salary
)
select *
from taxes
where country_alpha3='USA' and year='2018' and active=true
and subdivision_code='US-MEDI'
and local_code is null
and start_date <= (SELECT calcdate from vars) and end_date >= (SELECT calcdate from vars)
and lower_amount_cents <= (SELECT salary from vars) and upper_amount_cents >= (SELECT salary from vars);
```